# How to deal with buffered strings from C in Swift?

Tags: swift, utf-8, libxml2, null-terminated

I'm working with libxml2's sax parser to read large xml files. Most callback handlers are provided a NULL terminated char pointer. Using `String.fromCString` these can be converted to a regular string in Swift. However sax uses a buffer for reading the bytes, so one of the callbacks (`characters`) might be called with part of a string, namely the size of the buffer. This partial string might even start/end halfway a Unicode code point. The callback will be called multi times, until the complete string is provided (in chunks).

I'm thinking of either concatenating all chunks until the complete string can be assembled, or somehow detecting codepoint boundaries in the partial strings, only processing complete up until the invalid codepoint.

What would be the best way to handle such circumstances? The processing should be as fast as possible, while still correct. Memory usage should be kept minimal, but not at the cost of performance.

Comment: I am not experienced with libxml2's sax parser, but [here](http://www.jamesh.id.au/articles/libxml-sax/libxml-sax.html#characters) it is said that *"In your callback, you will probably want to copy the characters to some other buffer ..."*. That can for example be done with NSMutableData.

Comment: If you're using `String.fromCString` then the data is encoded in UTF-8. You could look at last few bytes of the buffer to see where the character boundary is, then create the partial string using NSMutableString(bytes:length:encoding:). Then save any extra bytes to prepend to the next buffer, repeat and append the subsequent strings to the end of the original.

Answer (score 2):

If processing speed is your first goal then I would just collect
all characters until the XML element is processed completely and
`endElement` is called. This can be done using `NSMutableData`
from the Foundation framework. So you need a property

```
var charData : NSMutableData?
```

which is initialized in `startElement`:

```
charData = NSMutableData()
```

In the `characters` callback you append all data:

```
charData!.appendBytes(ch, length: Int(len))
```

(The forced unwrapping is acceptable here. `charData` can only be `nil`
if `startElement` has not been called before, which means that you
made a programming error or libxml2 is not working correctly).

Finally in `endElement`, create a Swift string 
and release the data:

```
defer {
    // Release data in any case before function returns
    charData = nil
}
guard let string =  String(data: charData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
    // Handle invalid UTF-8 data situation
} 
// string is the Swift string
```

Comment: Thanks for the interesting approach. Would there be a way to do this without the ObjC runtime? Instead of waiting for `endElement`, one could as well check the last byte of `characters` for `NULL` right?

Comment: @bouke: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. There is no NULL in characters. What do you want to check? (Note that many Swift functions use Foundation under the hood, so that library is used anyway). – If you want to detect *invalid input* before endElement is called then this approach does not work and you have to proceed e.g. as in Rob's answer. That *might* be slower because the data is moved more often, but you have to test it yourself.

Comment: If copying performance is a concern, note that it's usually easier to reason about `NSData` performance than `[UInt8]` performance (look in the edits for my original `NSData` implementation). Arrays are value types with copy-on-write, but also single-reference optimizations to avoid copies. That makes it challenging to know precisely when they'll be copied if you manipulating them. `NSMutableData` is a reference type, so there are never implicit copies due to mutation. I switched to a `[UInt8]` implementation because the code is slightly simpler to read, not because it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

The longest legal UTF-8 character is 4 bytes ([RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) Section 3). So you don't need a very big buffer to keep yourself safe. The rules for how many bytes you'll need are pretty easy, too (just look at the first byte). So I would just maintain an buffer that holds from 0 to 3 bytes. When you have the right number, pass it along and try to construct a String. Something like this (only lightly tested, may have corner cases that don't work still):

```
final class UTF8Parser {
    enum Error: ErrorType {
        case BadEncoding
    }
    var workingBytes: [UInt8] = []

    func updateWithBytes(bytes: [UInt8]) throws -> String {

        workingBytes += bytes

        var string = String()
        var index = 0

        while index < workingBytes.count {
            let firstByte = workingBytes[index]
            var numBytes = 0

                 if firstByte < 0x80 { numBytes = 1 }
            else if firstByte < 0xE0 { numBytes = 2 }
            else if firstByte < 0xF0 { numBytes = 3 }
            else                     { numBytes = 4 }

            if workingBytes.count - index < numBytes {
                break
            }

            let charBytes = workingBytes[index..<index+numBytes]

            guard let newString = String(bytes: charBytes, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
                throw(Error.BadEncoding)
            }
            string += newString
            index += numBytes
        }

        workingBytes.removeFirst(index)
        return string
    }
}

let parser = UTF8Parser()
var string = ""
string += try parser.updateWithBytes([UInt8(65)])

print(string)
let partial = try parser.updateWithBytes([UInt8(0xCC)])
print(partial)

let rest = try parser.updateWithBytes([UInt8(0x81)])
print(rest)

string += rest
print(string)
```

This is just one way that's kind of straightforward. Another approach that is probably faster would be to walk backwards through the bytes, looking for the last start of code point (a byte that doesn't start with "10"). Then you could process everything up to that point in one fell swoop, and special-case just the last few bytes.

Comment: Interesting approach as well, only carrying the left over bytes would probably improve performance, requiring less copying.

Comment: You could of course create more special cases to avoid even more copying. For instance, since you know how many byte you want out of `bytes`, you could slice those off and append them to `workingBytes`, then work with the rest as a slice. In my experience, if copying is a serious concern, then `NSMutableData` is the better tool, because it has much more predictible copying rules, and has "noCopy" optimizations for working with foreign buffers. You can also work in UnsafeMutableBufferPointers, but these can also be very tricky to use correctly.

Comment: See http://robnapier.net/nsdata for my much longer rant on leaving and returning to `NSMutableData`, almost entirely over copying concerns.