# What is a safe way to turn streamed (utf8) data into a string?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, utf-8

Suppose I'm a server written in objc/swift. The client is sending me a large amount of data, which is really a large utf8 encoded string. As the server, i have my NSInputStream firing events to say it has data to read. I grab the data and build up a string with it.

However what if the next chunk of data I get falls on an unfortunate position in the utf8 data? Like on a composed character.  It seems like it would mess the string up if you try to append a chunk of non compliant utf8 to it.

What is a suitable way to deal with this?  I was thinking I could just keep the data as an NSData, but then I don't have anyway to know when the data has finished being received (think HTTP where the length of data is in the header).

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: do you want to show partial strings? the connection will always close / end when all the data has been received

Comment: In this case I may get multiple messages from the client at once. I need to scan the data as string to break it up.

Comment: the only way is to check your stream byte, by byte. you can see, if the next unicode character is represented by one, two, three, four, five or six bytes, and append to your string the whole character. so some intermediate buffer is necessary.

Comment: *How* do you break the string up into messages? A newline (or any 7-bit ASCII character) is always a single UTF-8 byte, so maybe you can collect the data until you receive a separating character, and then convert the collected bytes.

Comment: @MartinR I used to use the same approach, until i have to split the data in predefined format (yes,  xml without whitespace between different tags, but with a lot whitespace inside tags)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool you probably want to use here is [`UTF8`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/type/UTF8/). It will handle all the state issues for you. See [How to cast decrypted UInt8 to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517002/how-to-cast-decrypted-uint8-to-string/34517832#34517832) for a simple example that you can likely adapt.

The major concern in building up a string from UTF-8 data isn't composed characters, but rather multi-byte characters. "LATIN SMALL LETTER A" + "COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT" works fine even if decode each of those characters separately. What doesn't work is gathering the first byte of 你, decoding it, and then appending the decoded second byte. The `UTF8` type will handle this for you, though. All you need to do is bridge your `NSInputStream` to a `GeneratorType`.

Here's a basic (not fully production-ready) example of what I'm talking about. First, we need a way to convert an `NSInputStream` into a generator. That's probably the hardest part:

```
final class StreamGenerator {
    static let bufferSize = 1024
    let stream: NSInputStream
    var buffer = [UInt8](count: StreamGenerator.bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)
    var buffGen = IndexingGenerator<ArraySlice<UInt8>>([])

    init(stream: NSInputStream) {
        self.stream = stream
        stream.open()
    }
}

extension StreamGenerator: GeneratorType {
    func next() -> UInt8? {
        // Check the stream status
        switch stream.streamStatus {
        case .NotOpen:
            assertionFailure("Cannot read unopened stream")
            return nil
        case .Writing:
            preconditionFailure("Impossible status")
        case .AtEnd, .Closed, .Error:
            return nil // FIXME: May want a closure to post errors
        case .Opening, .Open, .Reading:
            break
        }

        // First see if we can feed from our buffer
        if let result = buffGen.next() {
            return result
        }

        // Our buffer is empty. Block until there is at least one byte available
        let count = stream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.capacity)

        if count <= 0 { // FIXME: Probably want a closure or something to handle error cases
            stream.close()
            return nil
        }

        buffGen = buffer.prefix(count).generate()
        return buffGen.next()
    }
}
```

Calls to `next()` can block here, so it should not be called on the main queue, but other than that, it's a standard Generator that spits out bytes. (This is also the piece that probably has lots of little corner cases that I'm not handling, so you want to think this through pretty carefully. Still, it's not that complicated.)

With that, creating a UTF-8 decoding generator is almost trivial:

```
final class UnicodeScalarGenerator<ByteGenerator: GeneratorType where ByteGenerator.Element == UInt8> {
    var byteGenerator: ByteGenerator
    var utf8 = UTF8()
    init(byteGenerator: ByteGenerator) {
        self.byteGenerator = byteGenerator
    }
}

extension UnicodeScalarGenerator: GeneratorType {
    func next() -> UnicodeScalar? {
        switch utf8.decode(&byteGenerator) {
        case .Result(let scalar): return scalar
        case .EmptyInput: return nil
        case .Error: return nil // FIXME: Probably want a closure or something to handle error cases
        }
    }
}
```

You could of course trivially turn this into a CharacterGenerator instead (using `Character(_:UnicodeScalar)`).

The last problem is if you want to combine all combining marks, such that "LATIN SMALL LETTER A" followed by "COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT" would always be returned together (rather than as the two characters they are). That's actually a bit trickier than it sounds. First, you'd need to generate Strings, not Characters. And then you'd need a good way to know what all the combining characters are. That's certainly knowable, but I'm having a little trouble deriving a simple algorithm. There's no "combiningMarkCharacterSet" in Cocoa. I'm still thinking about it. Getting something that "mostly works" is easy, but I'm not sure yet how to build it so that it's correct for all of Unicode.

Here's a little sample program to try it out:

```
    let textPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("text.txt", ofType: nil)!
    let inputStream = NSInputStream(fileAtPath: textPath)!
    inputStream.open()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)) {
        let streamGen = StreamGenerator(stream: inputStream)
        let unicodeGen = UnicodeScalarGenerator(byteGenerator: streamGen)
        var string = ""
        for c in GeneratorSequence(unicodeGen) {
            print(c)
            string += String(c)
        }
        print(string)
    }
```

And a little text to read:

```
Here is some normalish álfa你好 text
And some Zalgo i̝̲̲̗̹̼n͕͓̘v͇̠͈͕̻̹̫͡o̷͚͍̙͖ke̛̘̜̘͓̖̱̬ composed stuff
And one more line with no newline
```

(That second line is some [Zalgo encoded text](http://www.eeemo.net), which is nice for testing.)

I haven't done any testing with this in a real blocking situation, like reading from the network, but it should work based on how `NSInputStream` works (i.e. it should block until there's at least one byte to read, but then should just fill the buffer with whatever's available).

I've made all of this match `GeneratorType` so that it plugs into other things easily, but error handling might work better if you didn't use `GeneratorType` and instead created your own protocol with `next() throws -> Self.Element` instead. Throwing would make it easier to propagate errors up the stack, but would make it harder to plug into `for...in` loops.

Comment: UTF8() reads (synchronously) from the generator until that is exhausted. How would that work if the data comes in chunks?

Comment: @MartinR With a dispatch queue. Your `next()` method can block until there is data available. I've been building some generators just like this that generate solutions to NP complete problems. `next()` can take hours to return, but that's ok.

Comment: lets have some chunk of data .. let strb = "alfa你好".utf8; var buff = strb.dropLast().generate(); buff now mimics that chunk (it is generator over that chunk). while applying utf.decode(&buff) i can reconstruct the valid part alfa你 and next .Error. How I am able to check the position of 'last valid byte'? I think, that is the trouble with this approach. I don't see how to solve it and how to save the 'tail' of my data.

Comment: The call to decode won't return until a full character is generated. That's why you'll need a second dispatch queue to feed it. If you'll sketch your specific use case a little more specifically I can show you in code.

Comment: thanks, so, if i have some chunk of data, i am not able to reconstruct the valid part of message, until the message contains the right numbers of bytes ( it will .EmptyInput as a returning value from last call uft.decode(&buff), resp. it never returns .Error, even if real error occurs and probably never returns nothing more ). I used to use a little bit different approach. It works like uft.decode(&buff) returning .Error(number_of_bytes_successfully_decoded). So i know, how much bytes i can remove from my receive buffer and i can add to it next chunk of data (when received from somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

I'm revisiting this question cause I've had the very same problem to solve.
My solution adopts the `UTF8.ForwardParser`, hence it works with chunks of `UInt8` values, keeping around the bytes of a scalar which might be among two consecutive chunks of bytes.

```
// This class generates chunks of bytes from the given InputStream
final class ChunksGenerator {
        static let bSize = 1024
        let stream: InputStream
        var buffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: bSize)
        
        init(_ stream: InputStream) {
            self.stream = stream
            self.stream.open()
        }
        
        // Pull a chunk of bytes from the stream
        func pull() throws -> ArraySlice<UInt8> {
            switch stream.streamStatus {
            // We've got to read the stream
            case .opening: fallthrough
            case .open: fallthrough
            case .reading: break
            
            // We're either done reading or having an error
            case .error: fallthrough
            case .atEnd:
                stream.close()
                if let error = stream.streamError {
                    throw error
                } else {
                    fallthrough
                }
            case .closed: fallthrough
            case .notOpen: return []
            
            // Let's also address other status 
            case .writing: fallthrough
            @unknown default: preconditionFailure("status: \(stream.streamStatus) not manageable for InputStream")
            }
            
            // read from stream in buffer
            let length = stream.read(&buffer, maxLength: Self.bSize)
            guard
                length > 0
            else {
                // Either stream.read(_&:maxLength:) returned 0 or -1
                defer {
                    stream.close()
                }
                if length == 0 {
                    
                    return []
                }
                
                throw stream.streamError!
            }
            
            return buffer.prefix(length)
        }
        
    }
    
    // This Iterator returns Character from an InputStream
    struct CharacterParser: IteratorProtocol {
        typealias Element = Character
        let chunksGenerator: ChunksGenerator
        var chunk: Array<UInt8> = []
        var chunkIterator: IndexingIterator<Array<UInt8>> = [].makeIterator()
        var error: Swift.Error? = nil
        var utf8Parser = UTF8.ForwardParser()
        
        init(inputStream: InputStream) {
            self.chunksGenerator = ChunksGenerator(inputStream)
            self.chunk = _pulledChunk ?? []
            self.chunkIterator = chunk.makeIterator()
        }
        
        mutating func next() -> Character? {
            switch utf8Parser.parseScalar(from: &chunkIterator) {
            case .valid(let encoded):
                // We've parsed a scalar encoded in UTF8,
                // let's decode it and return the Character:
                let scalar = UTF8.decode(encoded)
                
                return Character(scalar)
            case .emptyInput:
                // We've consumed this chunk of bytes,
                // let's pull another one from the stream
                // and update the iterator underlaying data: 
                chunk = _pulledChunk ?? []
                self.chunkIterator = chunk.makeIterator()
                guard
                    // In case we've pulled an empty one then
                    // we're done and we return nil
                    !chunk.isEmpty
                else { return nil }
                
                return next()
            case .error(length: let length):
                // We've gotten a parsing error, therefore
                // the suffix of the actual chunk up to the
                // length from the parse error contains bytes
                // of a potential encoded scalar spanning 
                // across two chunks:
                let remaninigChunk = chunk.suffix(length)
                let pulledChunk = _pulledChunk ?? []
                chunk = remaninigChunk + pulledChunk
                chunkIterator = chunk.makeIterator()
                guard
                    chunk.count > remaninigChunk.count
                else {
                    // No more data could be pulled from the stream:
                    // this is it, the stream ends with bytes that aren't an UTF8 scalar, thus we set the error and return nil.
                    self.error = DecodingError.dataCorrupted(DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Parse error. Bytes: \(remaninigChunk) cannot be parsed into a valid UTF8 scalar", underlyingError: self.error))
                    
                    return nil
                }
                
                return next()
            }
        }
        
        // Attempt to pull a chunk from the stream,
        // in case there was an error we set it in this
        // iterator and return nil.
        private var _pulledChunk: Array<UInt8>? {
            mutating get {
                do {
                    let pulled = try chunksGenerator.pull()
                    
                    return Array(pulled)
                } catch let e {
                    self.error = e
                    
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
```